# Enterprise Architect Relationship Matrix Element Grouping

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am struggling with Enterprise Architect Relationship Matrices and would like to know if it is possible to group elements on the X and Y axis such as show in the figure below:

[image: Example element grouping in a relationship matrix]

In the previous example elements 1 - 5 on the horizontal axis are grouped into label "Financial" and elements from 6 - 10 are grouped into label "Customer". On the vertical axis elements from 01 - 06 are grouped into label "Financial".

I would like to use the same structuring with an Enterprise Architect Relationship Matrix.

I already tried to put these elements in different packages and have the pakage name prefixed on the element name. However in that case all elements are ordered alphabetically which is not the desired behaviour.

[image: Alphabetic ordering of elements in relationship matrix]

If it was possible to colour the elements this would be an alternative for me.

So my question is, is this somehow possible or is there an alternative way to achieve a similar outcome?

Thank you for your help and suggestions!
Ronald

Comment: Additionally to what Geert said you can send a feature request.

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid that is not possible.

As an alternative you could include the type of element into the name of the elements.
Something like

```
FIN - 002 - IT Compliance and support of..
INT - 012 - Enablement and support of...
```

Comment: Hi Geert, thanks for your quick response. I first thought of that too but I am always a little bit reluctant to use textual coding to express formal relationships. However I see that this may be the only way to achieve something similar. Thanks again for your quick help! Ronald